# Need help understanding usage of bitwise operators

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I inherited some code and can't figure out one piece of it:

```
byte[] b = new byte[4] { 3, 2, 5, 7 };
int c = (b[0] & 0x7f) << 24 | b[1] << 16 | b[2] << 8 | b[3];
```

Can anyone tell what's happening here?

Comment: You want to give us a little context about where you found this code?  Or is this just a test?

Comment: @Nix is where he got it really relevant?

Comment: @MGZero now that it has been answered no..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Basically it converts the lower 31 bits of a 4 byte array into an integer using a [big-endian conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

So a byte array of { 0, 0, 0, 1 } would be converted to 1; a byte array of { 0, 0, 1, 0 } would be converted to 256 etc.

It does this through a mixture of bitwise operators:

- `&` is [bitwise "and"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx)
- `|` is [bitwise "or"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx.aspx)
- `<<` is the [left shift operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1sway8w.aspx)

Comment: Any detailed info on this? Links, etc. I'd appreciate that.

Comment: @Kizz: I was just editing with links for each operator. What else do you need?

Comment: It puzzles me why Stackoverflow won't let me accept an answer for a certain period of time?

Comment: @MTG: So that it gives an opportunity for someone to post a better one.

Answer (score 5):

haven't done bit math in a minute so..for fun:
[extra parenthesis to show order of ops]

```
((b[0] & 0x7f) << 24) | (b[1] << 16) | (b[2] << 8) | b[3]

(b[0] & 0x7f) << 24 =  11 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
b[1] << 16 = . . . . . . . . . . 10 0000 0000 0000 0000
b[2] << 8 = . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 101 0000 0000
b[3] = .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 0111
```

now OR these together, and you get

```
0011 0000 0010 0000 0101 0000 0111 = 50,464,007
```